# What is the meaning of "Attribute with this code is not super in rows: 7, 10" in magento 2 product importer?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to import 2 configurable products with their variations from one magento installation to another, and get this error message when I Check the Data.

---

**EDIT : example given by @Dariodor**

```
15:35:55 - 188MB Attribute with this code is not super on lines 1,3,9,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,30,33,37,42,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,77,79,82,85,88,91,93,95,98
15:35:55 - 188MB Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors on lines 2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,22,26,27,28,29,31,32,34,35,36,38,39,40,41,43,44,45,47,48,50,51,53,54,56,57,59,60,62,63,65,66,68,69,71,72,74,75,76,78,80,81,83,84,86,87,89,90,92,94,96,97,99,100
15:35:55 - 188MB Debugging first 5 error lines 1,3,9,14,15
15:35:55 - 188MB
+---------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| key                                   | 0             | 1             | 2             | 3             | 4             |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| _store                                |               |               |               |               |               |
| ho_import_profile                     | import_prod… | import_prod… | import_prod… | import_prod… | import_prod… |
| sku                                   | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| _type                                 | configurable  | configurable  | configurable  | configurable  | configurable  |
| _attribute_set                        | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… |
| _product_websites                     | base          | base          | base          | base          | base          |
| name                                  | CARTELLA PRO… | CARTELLA 2 S… | CARTELLA PRO… | ACCESSORI VI… | ACCESSORI VI… |
| short_description                     | 00 NERO       | NERO          | NERO          | NERO          | NERO          |
| description                           | CARTELLA PRO… | CARTELLA A 2… | CARTELLA PRO… | Per una buon… | 2 porta indi… |
| status                                | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             |
| url_key                               | cartella-pro… | cartella-2-s… | cartella-pro… | accessori-vi… | accessori-vi… |
| visibility                            | 4             | 4             | 4             | 4             | 4             |
| price                                 | 67.5          | 67.5          | 103.5         | 6.5           | 11            |
| special_price                         | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| special_from_date                     | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| ebay_price                            | 71            | 71            | 109           | 6.5           | 11            |
| tax_class_id                          | 5             | 5             | 5             | 5             | 5             |
| is_in_stock                           | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             |
| news_from_date                        | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| ean                                   | 3219110245714 | 3219110245738 | 3219110260328 | 3219110225228 | 3219110261783 |
| manufacturer                          | DELSEY        | DELSEY        | DELSEY        | DELSEY        | DELSEY        |
| categories                            | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | UNISEX        | UNISEX        |
| stagione                              | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| categoria_ebay                        | 52357         | 52357         | 52357         | 93839         | 93839         |
| categoria_ebay_2                      | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| categoria_store_ebay                  | 1131970319    | 1131970319    | 1131970319    | 1131970319    | 1131970319    |
| shipping_world                        | 6.50          | 6.50          | 6.50          | 6.50          | 6.50          |
| shipping_inter                        | 18.00         | 18.00         | 18.00         | 18.00         | 18.00         |
| _super_products_sku                   | 2224567701011 | 2224567801018 | 2224567601014 | 2222331001008 | 2224592801014 |
| _super_attribute_price_corr           | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| _super_attribute_code                 | size,color    | size,color    | size,color    | size,color    | size,color    |
| _super_attribute_option               | UNICA -- .,m… | UNICA -- .,m… | UNICA -- .,m… | UNICA -- .,m… | UNICA -- .,m… |
| _media_image                          | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| _media_attribute_id                   | 80            | 80            | 80            | 80            | 80            |
| _media_is_disabled                    | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             |
| _media_position                       | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             |
| _media_lable                          | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| image                                 | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| image_label                           | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| small_image                           | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| small_image_label                     | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| thumbnail                             | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| thumbnail_label                       | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| m2e_observe_product                   | 22447         | 22448         | 22449         | 10728         | 10729         |
| Attribute with this code is not super | ERROR         | ERROR         | ERROR         | ERROR         | ERROR         |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your import data?

Answer (score 1):

```
15:35:55 - 188MB Attribute with this code is not super on lines 1,3,9,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,30,33,37,42,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,77,79,82,85,88,91,93,95,98
15:35:55 - 188MB Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors on lines 2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,22,26,27,28,29,31,32,34,35,36,38,39,40,41,43,44,45,47,48,50,51,53,54,56,57,59,60,62,63,65,66,68,69,71,72,74,75,76,78,80,81,83,84,86,87,89,90,92,94,96,97,99,100
15:35:55 - 188MB Debugging first 5 error lines 1,3,9,14,15
15:35:55 - 188MB
+---------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| key                                   | 0             | 1             | 2             | 3             | 4             |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| _store                                |               |               |               |               |               |
| ho_import_profile                     | import_prod… | import_prod… | import_prod… | import_prod… | import_prod… |
| sku                                   | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| _type                                 | configurable  | configurable  | configurable  | configurable  | configurable  |
| _attribute_set                        | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… | Prodotto ges… |
| _product_websites                     | base          | base          | base          | base          | base          |
| name                                  | CARTELLA PRO… | CARTELLA 2 S… | CARTELLA PRO… | ACCESSORI VI… | ACCESSORI VI… |
| short_description                     | 00 NERO       | NERO          | NERO          | NERO          | NERO          |
| description                           | CARTELLA PRO… | CARTELLA A 2… | CARTELLA PRO… | Per una buon… | 2 porta indi… |
| status                                | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             |
| url_key                               | cartella-pro… | cartella-2-s… | cartella-pro… | accessori-vi… | accessori-vi… |
| visibility                            | 4             | 4             | 4             | 4             | 4             |
| price                                 | 67.5          | 67.5          | 103.5         | 6.5           | 11            |
| special_price                         | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| special_from_date                     | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| ebay_price                            | 71            | 71            | 109           | 6.5           | 11            |
| tax_class_id                          | 5             | 5             | 5             | 5             | 5             |
| is_in_stock                           | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             | 1             |
| news_from_date                        | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| ean                                   | 3219110245714 | 3219110245738 | 3219110260328 | 3219110225228 | 3219110261783 |
| manufacturer                          | DELSEY        | DELSEY        | DELSEY        | DELSEY        | DELSEY        |
| categories                            | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | UNISEX        | UNISEX        |
| stagione                              | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| categoria_ebay                        | 52357         | 52357         | 52357         | 93839         | 93839         |
| categoria_ebay_2                      | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| categoria_store_ebay                  | 1131970319    | 1131970319    | 1131970319    | 1131970319    | 1131970319    |
| shipping_world                        | 6.50          | 6.50          | 6.50          | 6.50          | 6.50          |
| shipping_inter                        | 18.00         | 18.00         | 18.00         | 18.00         | 18.00         |
| _super_products_sku                   | 2224567701011 | 2224567801018 | 2224567601014 | 2222331001008 | 2224592801014 |
| _super_attribute_price_corr           | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   | ###EMPTY###   |
| _super_attribute_code                 | size,color    | size,color    | size,color    | size,color    | size,color    |
| _super_attribute_option               | multicolore   | multicolore   | multicolore   | multicolore   | multicolore   |
| _media_image                          | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| _media_attribute_id                   | 80            | 80            | 80            | 80            | 80            |
| _media_is_disabled                    | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             |
| _media_position                       | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             | 0             |
| _media_lable                          | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| image                                 | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| image_label                           | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| small_image                           | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| small_image_label                     | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| thumbnail                             | 22245677-1.j… | 22245678-1.j… | 22245676-1.j… | 22223310-1.j… | 22245928-1.j… |
| thumbnail_label                       | 22245677      | 22245678      | 22245676      | 22223310      | 22245928      |
| m2e_observe_product                   | 22447         | 22448         | 22449         | 10728         | 10729         |
| Attribute with this code is not super | ERROR         | ERROR         | ERROR         | ERROR         | ERROR         |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

In my case, _super_attribute_option contains a value "multicolore" that there is not in child simple-product attribute "color" assigned to this configurable product

Hope that helps.